# Why doesn't Octave's 'save' function support single precision for MAT-files

Tags: octave, mat-file

I have Octave 3.2-4 on Ubuntu 11.10. This is the officially supported version for Ubuntu. Where it seems that GNU Octave's `save` function does not support binary data saving in single precision float format in MAT-files. For instance:

```
octave:119> p_t = single(rand(1,5))
p_t =
   0.038507   0.117961   0.894508   0.788297   0.651727

octave:120> class(p_t)
ans = single

octave:121> save -v6 P_T.mat p_t
octave:122> clear all
octave:123> load -v6 P_T.mat p_t
octave:124> p_t
p_t =
   0.038507   0.117961   0.894508   0.788297   0.651727

octave:125> class(p_t)
ans = double
```

I have tried searching for a known issue of Octave, but could not find anything...
Anyone else noticed this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade. That has already been fixed.

"*officially supported version for Ubuntu*"? That means absolutely nothing. And even if you mean "latest version packaged by Ubuntu", it would be false. Anyway:

- you are using an old Ubuntu version. The latest Ubuntu already has Octave 3.6.2
- you are using an old Octave version (almost 3 years old. There's been 7 releases of Octave since, including 2 major releases)

So there's 2 things you can do:

- update your Ubuntu for 12.10
- update your Octave version, either [compiling from source](http://wiki.octave.org/Debian) or using a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave)

Comment: Upgrading to latest Octave release solved the problem. Thanks for your help!